# How to convert query into codeigniter command?

Tags: codeigniter

model:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT count(*) as c from event where id=48 and Ev_id=352");

if($query == 0){
   $act = array(
   'ev_id' => $ev_id,
   'id'   =>  $id ,
   'count' => '1'
);
//print_r($act);
$this->db->insert('join()', $act);

 }
else{
     echo"Unable to join";
```

Comment: Where have you defined `$ev_id` and `$id` ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [manual](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/examples.html):

you should use

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
```

an insert is made like this:

```
$data = array(
               'title' => $title,
               'name' => $name,
               'date' => $date
            );

$this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
```

Comment: but it is not working properly,showing error like this,
Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/codeIgniter/application/models/usermodel.php on line 79

Comment: no it rerun properly i only cant able to fetch the num_rows

Comment: in /application/config/autoload.php  add $autoload['libraries'] = array('database');  in /application/config/database.php configure you database settings in /application/config/config.php set up other stuff. make sure you've created the table with the fields in the database and you model is extending CI_Model and the function index() is calling parent::__construct();